# C++ not recognizing getline()

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a coding assignment done and I am getting to the part where I need to code it so the user can input a character to make a decision. For the assignment I am required to store the variable as a string, so I have been trying to use the get line() function to allow for the input. The problem that I am having is when I run the program it doesn't allow for me to input any string character at all and instead just runs right through the error check. Lines 30 and 31 are where I am having trouble, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variable Declarations 
    double num1,num2;
    string input;
    
    
//step 1
    
    cout<<"ECE 0301 - Vectors in R2 and Complex Numbers\nPlease enter two numbers, separated by a space,\nthat will represent a vector or a complex number."<< endl << endl;
    
//step 2 
    
    //asking for input
    cin>> num1 >> num2;
    
    //outputting
    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << "You entered " << num1 << " and " << num2 << "." << endl;
    
//step 3
    
    cout <<"\nAre these numbers in Cartesian (C) or polar (P) coordinates?\nPlease enter a single character as your choice.\n";
    getline(cin,input);
    
    
    //error check
    if(input != "c" || input != "C" || input != "p" || input != "P")
        {
            cout <<"\nERROR! Invalid selection,exiting.";
            return 0;
        }
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: After entering both numbers, newline is being taken by getline.You can try flushing buffer before getline statement.

Comment: Handle main function properly , return is within last if condition